# gsutil cp / download file to windows server

Tags: gsutil

I'm very new at this and need some help; I'm sure I'm not doing something right. I have a Synology NAS that has a cool options to sync files to Google cloud storage. This is a great way to get my backups off site 

I have my backups syncing to a cold line storage bucket. Now that my files are syncing I'm looking to document the process if I need to retrieve them.

I want to download a whole folder and all of the files inside it to a windows server. I installed the gsutil and trying to run this command.

```
gsutil -m cp -R dir gs://bhp_backup_sync/backup/foldername
```

but after I run this I get the following exception.

> CommandException: No URLs matched: dir
> CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.

NOOB here what am I missing?

Comment: I found out what i was doing wrong such a silly problem but i am learning this. i not have my backups of servers syncing to google cloud for safe keeping.

Comment: Here is what i was doing wrong in case anyone else runs wants to know. Here is the command                                                                                  gsutil -m cp -R *.* gs://bhp_backup_sync/backup/foldername c:\downloadlocation